# How to create custom box in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Like on the image below:

[image: mystery box]

Is it a modified/customized NSBox class?

Comment: well it is a subclass of NSView right... so you add all that stuff as subviews right... what have you tried, where are you getting hung up?

Comment: I just switched to XCode and NSBox seemed to be that element, but I could not find a way to customize the title to match the look of that image.

Comment: Well it shouldn't be to hard. Have you looked at NSBox tasks? All the stuff you need is in the NSBox Class. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

NSBox has a 'Custom' type but not sure whether such look can be achieved with one property.
The best I can make is to have NSBox inside NSBox. Additionally use labels and Horizontal lines to achieve the look.

The outer box can be of type: Primary, Border Type: Line. 
Inside Box Type: Custom, Border Type: None, Fill color : match the look.

You can tweak a bit to achieve the look and feel of the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RoundedBox](http://mattgemmell.com/roundedbox-nsbox-subclass/) by Matt Gemmell

> RoundedBox is an NSBox subclass with a rounded border and a
>   gradient-filled background. It's a new visual style of NSBox, with the
>   same basic functionality.

[image]

Gradient background is drawn using the Core Image API